# open javascript function in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I work on MySQL PHP

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<a href=javascript:click('$row[Name]')>".$row['Name']."</a>";
  echo "<br><br><br>";
 }
```

But in result:

```
<a href="javascript:click('Slow" cooker="" pepper="" steak')="">Slow Cooker Pepper Steak</a>
```

javascript

```
clikc(name)
{
alert("test");
}
```

what is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with your concatenation. Try this:

```
 echo "<a href=javascript:click('".$row['Name']."')>".$row['Name']."</a>";
```

And `clikc(name)` must be `click(name)`.

Comment: @NiceMan what is the result now ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your `href` value and you should encode the data for the medium you are outputting to in case your data contains characters that might break your html or javascript.

So you could use something like:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:click(" . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['Name']))) . ");\">"
     . htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . "</a>";
```

Comment: Remove the quotes inside the `click` parentheses if you're using `json_encode`

Comment: That said, `json_encode` will use double-quotes, which will just give the same problem again. You also need to `htmlspecialchars` the `json_encode`.

Comment: @Kolink Thanks for reminding me why I never write javascript like this.

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Personally I'd prefer putting the value in a `data-*` attribute and accessing it with `this.getAttribute`... but that won't work for a `javascript:` href due to `this` referring to the window. Joy!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use vars like this, you should escape them

version 1:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:click('".addslashes($row['Name'])."');\">".$row['Name']."</a>";
```

version 2,cleaner:

```
$value = addslashes($row['Name']);
echo <<<EOD
<a href="#" onclick="click('{$value}');return false;">{$row['Name']}</a>
EOD;
```

version 3,clean js also:

a) php:

```
$value = addslashes($row['Name']);
echo <<<EOD
<a href="#" class='js-clicky' data-value="{$value}">{$row['Name']}</a>
EOD;
```

b) html, using jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.js-clicky').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value');
})
</script>
```

Read here about :

heredoc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

addslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

jquery : http://jquery.com/